# Canvas URL cannot be a Facebook URL

Tags: url, canvas, facebook-page

I am trying set the address of Canvas URL.
 When My setting is :

```
http://10.137.189.18:33200/EPG/jsp/webtv/modules/social/success/
```

It got an error: 
       Canvas URL cannot be a Facebook URL

But when my setting  is :

```
http://10.135.189.18:33200/EPG/jsp/webtv/modules/social/success/
```

It is ok.
Why ?

Comment: Too little information here - from what address do your client application load from? How do you try to load the url? Is the url an image? Are you loading the url directly to canvas (how) ? Can you show a little more code.

Answer (score 2):

Try localhost or other domain. IP doesn't work anymore.